# Stack a video/audio download when a click event happens

Tags: jquery, video, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an accordion, based on BootStrap's collapse components. All is working fine with that, but my next task is to load the relevant video when a panel is open. As it's possible to have over 10 video's on a page I don't want them all loading when the page loads. Currently, i have preload="none" so nothing loads. Currently the video starts to load when the user clicks play on the control panel, and i'm looking to start the download when the panel is open.

Here's an example of the rendered HTML for a panel

```html
<div class="panel panel-default even">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href="#accordionPanel1" class="panel-title-link accordionPanel1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#PresentationAccordion" aria-expanded="true"><span class="count">1.</span><span class="title">Webinar One</span></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="accordionPanel1" class="panel-collaspe collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labeledby="panel1" aria-expanded="true">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-8 synopsis">
            <section class="webinarSynopsis">
              <h1>Webinar One</h1>
              <p>This is a Webinar synopsis.</p>
              <p>Wednesday, February 24, 2016</p>
              <p><a href="/Resources/Files/CY2015-Sales-Force-Activity-Report-With-French-(2).aspx" target="_blank">Webinar One</a></p>
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 video">
            <video controls="" preload="none" class="accordionPanel1 video1">
              <source src="/getmedia/41ea7d1c-f8b3-4977-aec8-3b195640fd57/2012_kick-off.mp4.aspx?width=300&amp;height=200&amp;ext=.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  //load video
})
```

This function will wait until the collapse is fully shown and visible to the user.